# How to distinguish variable and object in php syntactically

Tags: php, syntax

I am a beginner. I am really stuck with how to know if it's a variable  or an object since it doesn't has a type. I saw some time object passed to a function with type name of class and it works fine.
I tried passing object to a function with and without of its class or interface type and it works fine.
So my question  is how to distinguish  these two while reading code.
Thank you good peoples

Comment: Can you give examples of the problems your having - it's sometimes easier to understand with a specific piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to distinguish them without context.

All you can really do is `var_dump($var);` or `print_r($var);` to see the type when debugging.

As you already said, PHP does now support Typehinting, but it is not required.

Some IDEs like PHPStorm allow you to CTRL+Click on a variable to see where it gets initiated. That's often a big help.

Comment: `get_class`/`gettype` can be used instead of `var_dump`/`print_r` if you just want to check the type without viewing the variable value.